# Check if 2 dates are between 2 other dates javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

Hello I am trying to see if 2 dates are between 2 other dates

Here is what I tried but it doesn't seem to work

```
checkSameDates = (selectedDate, removedDates) => {
    return (
      new Date(removedDates.startDate) >= new Date(selectedDate.startDate) &&
      new Date(selectedDate.endDate) <= new Date(removedDates.endDate)
    );
  };
```

```
selectedDate is 15/6/2021 to 17/6/2021
removedDates is 15/6/2021 to 15/6/2021
```

Any ideas on what is wrong?

Comment: In your case I would compare them with getTime(). The getTime() function returns the number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 as an integer-- should be trivial to determine if Two integers falls between two other integers.

Comment: I guess its about your date format. Try to send YYYY-MM-DD format or convert your string date manually to normal date.

Comment: May you share the data used when calling the function?

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqcn8jzr/2/) link.

```
function formatDates(strDate) {
   var parts = strDate.split('/');
   var retVal = new Date(parseInt(parts[2]), parseInt(parts[1] - 1), parseInt(parts[0]));
   console.log(retVal.toLocaleString());
   return retVal;
}
```